# How to run .sh file, using process builder?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, processbuilder

I already create the .sh file, and the inside is:

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:00 -j DROP
```

It works normally when I run it on the terminal, but when I use processbuilder, it didn't do anything. No error, but didn't happen anything, this is the code on my java:

```
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","/my/file.sh").start();
```

I already looking for the answer, but I still failed to run the .sh file, even I do the same thing with people that already done it.
Sorry if this is a bad question, thank you.

Comment: Probably waiting for passwords. Have you set up sudo without password for the user?

Comment: Do you want to Use Processbuilder only or something other workaround may also work

Comment: What is your command look like in terminal?

Comment: @LukeLee Thank you so much, after i change sudo setting, it finally work! :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the bash is not run? Do you checked the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object returned by the `start`method? You can get the output value, the output stream, etc. from this objects.

Answer (score 0):

Check your streams and exitvalue for errors... sudo is probably the problem here.

Not necessarily the best code but it gets the job done. Executes a process, takes the process.streams and prints them to System.out. Might helpt to find out what the issue actually is atlest.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    final Process proc = pb.start();    

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Process output");

    final Thread logThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                try {
                    String line;

                    do {
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        builder.append("");
                        builder.append(line == null ? "" : line);
                        builder.append("<br/>");    
                    } while(line != null);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Exception!  ").append(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        builder.append("Exception! ").append(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    logThread.start();
    int retVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java API Runtime : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

```
// Java runtime
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Command
String[] command = {"/bin/bash", "/my/file.sh"};
// Process
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

Also you should be careful with `sudo` commands that may ask for `root` password.